How to pipe expressions from a list of expressions in Python Polars
I cannot get my head around this.
Say that I have a dictionary of  regexes and replacement strings that I want to replace, and if none of these regexes are matched (when returns False) I want to resume with the next when statement.
So, instead of this way, that does not check for data in "new data"...
all_items = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "data": ["Swedish fish", "English tea", "", "", ""],
        "ISO_codes": ["fin", "nor", "eng", "eng", "swe"],           
    })


replacement_rules = {
    r"^Swe.*": "Svenska",
    r"^Eng.*": "English",
    
}

iso_tranlation = {
   "swe": "Svenska",
   "eng": "English",
   "nor": "Norsk",
   "fin": "Finska på finska",

}

for pattern, replacement in replacement_rules.items():
    all_items = (
        all_items.lazy()
        .with_columns(
            pl.when(pl.col("data").str.contains(pattern))
            .then(pl.lit(replacement))
            .alias("new_data")
        )
        .collect()
    ) 

all_items = (
    all_items.lazy()
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col("ISO_codes").str.len_chars() > 0)
        .then(
            pl.col("ISO_codes")
            .replace(iso_tranlation , default="Unknown ISO Code")
        )
        .alias("new_data")
    )
    .collect()
)

...i would like to do something along the lines of this:
expressions = [
    pl.when(pl.col("data").str.contains(pattern))
    .then(pl.lit(replacement))
     for pattern, replacement in replacement_rules.items()]

all_items = (
    all_items.lazy()
    .with_columns(
        expressions.explode_and_pipe()
        .when(pl.col("ISO_codes").str.len_chars() > 0)
        .then(
            pl.col("ISO_codes")
            .replace(iso_tranlation , default="Unknown ISO Code")
        )
        .alias("new_data")
    )
    .collect()
)

Is there a way to achieve that expressions.explode_and_pipe()?
EDIT:
This is the resulting dataframe i'm after:
shape: (5, 3)
┌──────────────┬───────────┬──────────┐
│ data         ┆ ISO_codes ┆ new_data │
│ ---          ┆ ---       ┆ ---      │
│ str          ┆ str       ┆ str      │
╞══════════════╪═══════════╪══════════╡
│ Swedish fish ┆ fin       ┆ Svenska  │
│ English tea  ┆ nor       ┆ English  │
│              ┆ eng       ┆ English  │
│              ┆ eng       ┆ English  │
│              ┆ swe       ┆ Svenska  │
└──────────────┴───────────┴──────────┘


Are you saying that all_data is not the correct output? i.e. the first row should be Svenska instead? If so, can you add the expected output?

so the goal is to short circuit and have each item of new_data be either the first matching replacement_rules for data, or if no matches found, the first matching iso_tranlation [sic] for ISO_code?

Maybe you are looking for something like this? (coalesce may be the function you want.)
replacements = pl.lit(None)
for pattern, replacement in replacement_rules.items():
    replacements = (
        pl.when(pl.col("data").str.contains(pattern))
        .then(pl.lit(replacement))
        .otherwise(replacements)
    )

iso_translations = pl.col("ISO_codes").replace(
    iso_translation, default="Unknown ISO Code"
)

all_items.with_columns(new_data=pl.coalesce(replacements, iso_translations))

shape: (5, 3)
┌──────────────┬───────────┬──────────┐
│ data         ┆ ISO_codes ┆ new_data │
│ ---          ┆ ---       ┆ ---      │
│ str          ┆ str       ┆ str      │
╞══════════════╪═══════════╪══════════╡
│ Swedish fish ┆ fin       ┆ Svenska  │
│ English tea  ┆ nor       ┆ English  │
│              ┆ eng       ┆ English  │
│              ┆ eng       ┆ English  │
│              ┆ swe       ┆ Svenska  │
└──────────────┴───────────┴──────────┘


Wow, reading up on coalesce, this seems like an approach that should work. I will try first thing tomorrow!

I borrowed your end result table.

when/then expressions can also be chained:
pl.when().then().when().then()

Which will give you if/elif semantics:
IF   ... 
ELIF ...
ELIF ...

False/None can be used as an initial "no-op" to build one programatically:
expr = pl.when(False).then(None)

for pattern, replacement in replacement_rules.items():
    expr = expr.when(pl.col("data").str.contains(pattern))
    expr = expr.then(pl.lit(replacement))
   
expr = expr.when(pl.col("ISO_codes").str.len_chars() > 0)
expr = expr.then(            
    pl.col("ISO_codes")
      .replace(iso_translation, default="Unknown ISO Code")
)

>>> df.with_columns(new_data = expr)
shape: (5, 3)
┌──────────────┬───────────┬──────────┐
│ data         ┆ ISO_codes ┆ new_data │
│ ---          ┆ ---       ┆ ---      │
│ str          ┆ str       ┆ str      │
╞══════════════╪═══════════╪══════════╡
│ Swedish fish ┆ fin       ┆ Svenska  │
│ English tea  ┆ nor       ┆ English  │
│              ┆ eng       ┆ English  │
│              ┆ eng       ┆ English  │
│              ┆ swe       ┆ Svenska  │
└──────────────┴───────────┴──────────┘


Very nice! This was the way I was initially pursuing. These two answers should prove very useful for people down the line.
